# Error found while loading /home/[username]/.profile

Tags: command-line, .profile

When the system loads it gives the following error:

```
Error found while loading /home/[username]/.profile 
mesg: ttyname failed: inappropriate ioctl for device
As a result the session should not be configured correctly
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible
```

The output of `grep -i mesg` for `.profile` and `.bash*` is as follows:

```
$ grep -i mesg .profile
mesg n || true
$ grep -i mesg .bash*
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `terminal`...

```
gedit .profile
```

change this:

```
mesg n || true
```

to this:

```
tty -s && mesg n || true
```

The .profile for the root account may require a similar (but slightly different) fix.

Answer (score 1):

**`stty -ixon` on `.profile`**

I had that command on my `.profile`, and it was causing the problem in Ubuntu 17.10.

I had put it there because of the recommendations on this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the accepted answer further, your shell initialisation scripts `.profile` and `.bashrc` (assuming you are using bash - otherwise each shell is different) are run in a number of different scenarios:

- interactive login - eg

  - if you log in via ssh
  - starting a graphical terminal  (terminal emulators vary on when they start up a new session - or can be configured)
- when a script is run as your user

  - automated jobs (eg cron)
  - just a regular shell script
  - older examples that are less common include startup files like `.xinitrc` and `.Xsession` files when you log in (X only)
  - non-interactive ssh - eg `ssh host ls`

The main important difference is whether the shell session is an "interactive" session on a "terminal" (aka tty) or not.  An interactive session assumes there is a person typing commands into the shell and has a terminal (eg to allow painting colours on the screen or draw progress bars or similar "terminal graphics").

For running scripts or cronjobs the shell runs as a non-interactive shell, and does not expect to have a terminal/tty.  Many programs detect if they have a terminal/tty and adjust their behaviour (eg not prompting a user) but not all do.  Using programs that require a terminal/tty when you don't have one can lead to odd behaviours - failures, hangs waiting for user input, etc,...

In ubuntu the bash startup flow is roughly ()

1. read `.profile` (all "sh"-like shells read this)
2. `.profile` dispatches `.bashrc`
3. `.bashrc` eventually has lines:

   ```
   # If not running interactively, don't do anything
   case $- in
       *i*) ;;
         *) return;;
   esac
   ```

That `case` in your bashrc stops parsing `.bashrc` if you are not running interactively.

So the best solution is to put any configuration that requires a tty *after* that part of your `.bashrc`

```
mesg n || true
```

The accepted answer has an alternative workaround using `tty -s` to detect if there is a terminal present (assuming that means an interactive session) - hence `tty -s && mesg n` runs `mesg n` only if `tty -s` succeeds.

On modern systems this difference might not that important, but remember *every* shell script (well every `sh` script) in your system runs your `.profile` and *every* bash script runs `.bashrc` - at least until the interactive check above.  So every line of code that is in those files *before* the interactive check, that really is for *you* when you are typing at a terminal is a waste of time for the computer and has the potential to drop confusing information like this error message.

Best-practice recommendations:

1. Only set environment variables (if really required) above the "interactive check"
2. Mostly leave `.profile` alone (there are some reasons why you might need to change it, but obey recommendation 1 still)
3. Move most of your customisation after the "interactive check" - eg aliases, completion, terminal tools (like `mesg`, `biff` etc,...), ssh-agents,...

This means scripts will run faster, and you don't need workarounds for your interactive tools.