# error found when loading /home/[username]/.profile (after installing OpenFOAM)

Tags: command-line, bash, login, bashrc

I recently installed OpenFOAM by this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKyHFwfGpVQ the software seems working but when I restart my PC and log in I find this error message

```
Error found when loading /home/[username]/.profile

/opt/openfoam5/etc/bashrc: line 139: _foamSource: command not found
/opt/openfoam5/etc/bashrc: line 144: _foamEval: command not found
```

and some more (you can see here: http://kepkuldes.com/images/297f7e56a50b6cb4f18ce5f34b4ec2fd.jpg

I already saw this [Error found while loading /home/[username]/.profile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918169/error-found-while-loading-home-username-profile) but for me there is no "mesg n" line.

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Someone already see this issue? There is any solution for it?

BR, Csabi

Comment: Did you try [User configuration](https://openfoam.org/download/5-0-ubuntu/)?  There is also a link for bug reporting at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Presumably you added something to your `~/.bashrc` (which is sourced from `~/.profile`) that itself sources `/opt/openfoam5/etc/bashrc`?

Comment: Hi, I yes, I tried the [User configuration](https://openfoam.org/download/5-0-ubuntu/). I added with `gedit ~/.bashrc` this two line to the end of the bashrc. But I have the same message. :(
`. /opt/openfoam5/etc/bashrc`
`source /opt/openfoam5/etc/bashrc`

Comment: Then the issue is with `/opt/openfoam5/etc/bashrc`, since it's trying to run commands that are not found. Maybe they are supposed to be in the PATH?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I searched this file exist. when I add to my `~/.bashrc` or my `~/.profile` I have two different error message. Same issue but if I add for the `~/.profile`, i have a longer list which he miss. But the software works, I tried.